# Send Welcome Email when an user is created from apex code

Tags: apex, email-template, digital-experience

I'm having an issue when creating an user from the apex code.
My code do the following:

```
    @future
    public static void createUser(Id contactId) {
        Contact contact = [SELECT Id, Email, FirstName, LastName, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :contactId];
        Profile profile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'My Community Profile'];
        
        User newUser = new User(
            Alias=getAlias(contact),
            Email=contact.Email,
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
            FirstName=contact.FirstName,
            LastName=contact.LastName,
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_US',
            contactId=contact.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/New_York',
            Username=contact.Email,
            CommunityNickname=getNick(contact),
            IsActive=true,
            ProfileId=profile.Id
        );

        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;       
        dmo.EmailHeader.triggerOtherEmail = true;
        dmo.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = true;       
        dmo.optAllOrNone = false;

        newUser.setOptions(dmo);
        insert newUser;
    }
```

On my digital experience site:

- I have the `My Community Profile` on the Members/Selected Profiles option
- I also have the option `Send welcome email` checked on the `Emails` section along with the template.
- I have a dedicated template for the new member welcome.
- The site is active.

After I run the code, I can see the user being created with the right profile. But the welcome message is not being sent.

What am I missing?

Comment: And this profile is assigned to the experience site? Does the site have the welcome email template selected?

Comment: yes, it's assigned and yes, the email template is selected

Comment: when you say that the profile is assigned to the experience site, you mean on the Members section, right ? if so, yes, it's assigned.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it wasn't working was because we need to give `All Email` option to the `Access Level` on deliverability

[image]

Now, it's working perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to the Salesforce-specific Stack Exchange. We've all done that before (not setting it to `All email`)! Thanks for coming back to add the answer, as that could help future readers.